# Stopping the multiple postbacks of ASP.NET linkbutton

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The problem is when the user has clicked on a Link Button that is causing the browser to post to the server, it will take some time for doing the operation in the server side (assume during post back, it will insert some records into database). So, in the mean time, the user has clicked the link button again and again, then those many times the page will get submitted to the server, so those many records will be inserted into the database. But the thing is whenever the user clicked on the Link button multiple times also I want to posted back to the server first time only but not on the subsequent requests. 
Somehow I have managed to fix the issue with JavaScript function in onclientclick but the below is the only scenario which not working

1. Whenever the client side validation failing that time the form is not submitting, because the ele.disabled is set to true and Testing function return false . I doesn’t not matter the validation is passed or failed.
2. Please help me  to achieve this scenario .. I have tried Page_ClientValidate() and almost tried all the option..

   ```
   function Testing()
    {
      try
       {
           var retunboolean = true;
           var ele = document.getElementById('<%=linkButtonTesting.ClientID%>');

           if (ele != null && !ele.disabled)
               retunboolean = true;
           else
               retunboolean = false;

           if (ele != null)
               ele.disabled = true;
       }
       catch (err)
       {
           alert(err.description);
       }
        return retunboolean;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple - you add a **timer that re-enable the button** after few seconds - or you re-enable it after the user moves the mouse from the link **using the mouse over** event.

In the first solution with the timer, you give some arrest to the user to see the error on the page...

With the second solution - when the user removes the mouse from the element you re-enable it right away...